# Why do qobject_cast and dynamic_cast fail in a slot connected to QWidget::destroyed?

Tags: qt, casting, qobject

I have a class Subclass, subclassed from QObject. I want to know when the item is deleted, so I connected this slot to the QWidget::destroyed() signal inherited by Subclass. But when I try to cast the argument to with qobject_cast, I get a zero result. The same result obtains from C++'s dynamic_cast. Why?

```
void MyClass::mySlot( QObject * item )
{
    qobject_cast<Subclass*>(item); // returns zero, even though item is a Subclass*
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683403/why-is-qobject-destroyed-signal-called-after-the-destruction ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that by the time QObject::destroyed() is emitted, your derived class Subclass has already been destroyed. This is implied by [the C++ order of destruction](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/calling-base-dtor.html). Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8683403/why-is-qobject-destroyed-signal-called-after-the-destruction) deals with a similar issue.

To get around this, you could either use C-style pointer casting (which is dispreferred), or rewrite your code to use a QObject instead.